# Why mini-css-extract-plugin does not creating css file for less?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack-4, mini-css-extract-plugin

I tried extract-text-webpack-plugin to extract css file, but it failed. The version of webpack is 4.16.3, so I use mini-css-extract-plugin to do that, failed too! I think it is not about the configuration of these plugins. There is my webpack config. [the code repo is here](https://github.com/capslocktao/adminBackstage). Success packaging,but no css file.

```
const baseConfig = require('./webpack.config.base')
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')
const merge = require('webpack-merge')
const path = require('path')
const productionConfig = merge(baseConfig, {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: {
    app: path.join(__dirname, '../src/index.js'),
    vendor: ['vue', 'vue-router', 'vuex', 'axios', 'element-ui']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '../build/public'),
    filename: 'js/[name].bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: 'js/[name].[chunkhash:8].chunk.js',
    publicPath: './public'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.css/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader'
        ],
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.less/,
        use: [
          MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
          'css-loader',
          'less-loader'
        ],
        include: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 1024,
              name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              publicPath: './public/img',
              outputPath: '/img'
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)(\?.*)?$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
           options: {
              limit: 80000,
              name: '[name].[hash:8].[ext]',
              publicPath: './public/fonts',
              outputPath: '/fonts'
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
           vendor: {
              test: /[\\/]node_modules[\\/]/,
              name: 'vendor',
              chunks: 'all'
          }
        }
      },
      runtimeChunk: true
    },
    plugins: [
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].[chunkhash:8].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].css'
      })
    ]
})
module.exports = productionConfig
```

Comment: Include any error messages.

Comment: no error message, just not extract css file

Comment: @caps were you able to resolve that .. i am also facing same issue.

Comment: No, I initialized another project with the same config like that, then the css file can be extracted, I was confused